# How to pass the search keyword listed in a file to the file command in gitbash in windows 10

Tags: bash, shell, find, xargs

I have a dictionary.txt which i will be using to search some files using find command.

example of dictionary.txt:

```
*.xlsx
*project*
```

I am trying to make this command works but no luck

`cat dictionary.txt | xargs -i find /d -iname '"{}"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used single quotes in the wrong way.

Change your command in `cat dictionary.txt | xargs -i find /d -iname "{}"`

Comment: Well, please upvote and mark as solution my post if you can!

Comment: my next issue is if i have more than one keywords in my dictionary.txt, the only being executed is the last keyword in the list. would you know what is the problem?